# How to change value in ArrayList of jSpinners ?

Tags: java, jframe

I try to create my Form application with using of jSpinners. For efficiency I got all jSpinners to ArrayList() and would like to set value 0 for each jSpinner.

declararation of ArrayList:

`public ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();`

filled ArrayList with jSpinners:

`mylist.add(jSpinner_500_e); mylist.add(jSpinner_200_e); mylist.add(jSpinner_100_e);`

Also I know, that function "set(index_of_arraylist, value) allow to change certain index of ArrayList, but in my jSpinners is property setValue() for setting certain value.

Someone know, how to use my ArrayList() and adjust jSpinners values in for loop? thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to change is to add type parameter to your ArrayList to let compiler know, what type of object it should expect there. Change:

`public ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();`

to:

`public ArrayList<JSpinner> mylist = new ArrayList<>();`

You can see use of "diamond operator" (`<>`) - it has been presented in JDK7 and it helps to reduce some unnecessary code and makes it a bit clearer. Now you can try some possibilities of walking through `mylist` and changing values of its contents:

There is for-each loop - you can translate it as "For each `JSpinner` from `mylist` do the code inside curly brackets:

```
for(JSpinner spinner : mylist) {
    spinner.setValue(valueYouWantToSet);
}
```

Another way of achieving the same result is creating an Iterator that walks through ArrayList and for each of its element does the specified action. You can see an example here:

```
Iterator<JSpinner> iterator = mylist.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    it.next().setValue(valueYouWantToSet);
}
```

You can also use simple for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
    mylist.get(i).setValue(valueYouWantToSet);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not valid for compiler" ? Could you provide an exact error message you get?

Comment: if I wanna use code you reccommended me above, jSpinner variable does not exist ... compiler offer me to create local variable jSpinner.. but it don`t help me

Comment: Try changing jSpinner to JSpinner as this is the correct class name. Tell me if it works better now.

Comment: He is using raw type for ArrayList, compiler doesn't know that ArrayList contains jSpinner objects.

Comment: Of course... I haven't noticed that. I'll try to improve my answer now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I need to restrict my arraylist on jSpinner type, am I right?

Comment: `  public ArrayList<JSpinner> mylist = new ArrayList<JSpinner>(); `

Comment: so simple, but I don`t realize that I did not restrict my ArrayList for JSpinners,, thanks so much for the advice

Comment: You can reduce this line: public ArrayList<JSpinner> mylist = new ArrayList<JSpinner>() with te use of "diamond operator <>": public ArrayList<JSpinner> mylist = new ArrayList<>(). Not that much, but it can make your code a bit clearer. I'm glad I could help, thanks to GCP too for help. If you find my answer helpful, you might want to consider upvoting and ticking my answer as an accepted one (on the left side). Wish you all the best.